# Why isn't this block working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I have this block, but for some reason, the UITableView is not reloading.  Any ideas why?  I am seeing the NSLog of Save in the console.

```
-(void)addRoutine
{    
    PFObject *routine = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"Routine"];
    [routine setObject:self.entered forKey:@"name"];    
    [routine saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Save!");
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            // There was an error saving the rotuine.
        }
    }];   
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does PFObject call the block? Is it called on the main thread? Maybe self.tableView returns nil? Maybe reloadData is called, but nothing has changes in the model?

Comment: I added a screenshot from the API doc if that helps.

Comment: I'd re-ask V1ru8's question: `Maybe self.tableView returns nil?`

Comment: No the documentation doesn't help much. You can check if the callback is no the main thread with [NSThread isMainThread]. But it's more likely that self.tableView is nil or nothing changes in your model on reload.

Comment: The model is fine, because when I restart the app, the table is updated with the new data.  So maybe its happening on the wrong thread.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check on what thread it is? (you can also set a breakpoint and look on what thread it is). And did you check the tableView for nil?

Comment: I did this and it NSLoged as yes: `if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {NSLog (@"Yes");`

Comment: Why are you testing for `error == nil`?  Shouldn't you be doing `if (succeeded)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh ok now I see the fault. You can't use self in the block. Because self is the block. So you're calling -tableView on the block, that can't return anything useful.
You have to define something like `__block id blockSelf = self` outside the block and then use `[blockSelf tableView]` inside the block. Do a `NSLog(@"%@",self)` inside and outside the block. You'll see it's not the same object.

edit:

That's just bullshit I told here and obviously doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I did that nslog inside and outside the block and got this both times `<RoutineTableViewController: 0x8b1a300>`

Comment: Hmm, what's the output of `NSLog(@"%@",[blockSelf tableView])`?

Comment: I did that inside the block and got `<UITableView: 0x10b27e00; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xe5404f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`

Comment: If `NSLog(@"%@",self)` returns the same both times, I was wrong with my answer. Forget that blockSelf stuff.

Comment: When calling `-reloadData` do you get any callbacks on the UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: I set a breakpoint at cellforindexpath and it is being called after reload

Comment: Well then everything is in perfect shape with your block and the reload. If the DataSource methods are called correct, the error must be in these methods. Do you return the correct number of rows? do you return the correct cells? Check on these things.

Comment: Ah man it seems you may be right.  In `viewDidLoad`, I call this method `- (void)loadData
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Routine"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.numberOfRoutines = objects.count;
            self.routineArray = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];   
}` Should I call it again before calling the reload on the tableview?

Comment: It looks a lot like you should! Call loadData instead of reload in your `-saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`

Comment: Yes I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks.